# div is not create before oninit function ececutes in openui5

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

Hi i need multi selected and tree structure drop down.
so i am using html control like

```
new sap.ui.core.HTML({
        content:  "<div id=\"multiselection\"><select id=\"myid\" multiple=\"multiple\"></select></div>",
        layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "L4 M4 S4"}),
    }),
```

and now i am getting ajax response in onInit function of mypage.controller.js as followes

```
 var optgroups = [{"label":"WKS-FINGER1","children":[{"label":"WKS1","value":"WKS1"}]},{"label":"WKS-FINGER3","children":[{"label":"WKS3","value":"WKS3"}]},{"label":"WKS-FINGER4","children":[{"label":"WKS4","value":"WKS4"}]},{"label":"WKS-FINGER5","children":[{"label":"WKS5","value":"WKS5"}]}];
```

and now i am binding here(note i am using bootstrap-multiselect.js)

```
     $('#myid').multiselect({
         enableClickableOptGroups: true,
         onChange: function(option, checked, selected,element) {
            var selection = [];
                 $('#myid option:selected').each(function() {
                selection.push([$(this).val() , $(this).data('order') ]);
            }); 
          //  alert(selection);
            sap.ui.controller("oui5mvc.odbbshift").someFunction(selection);
         }
     });
     $('#myid').multiselect('dataprovider', optgroups);
```

the problem is i am not getting myid.i checked like this

```
var myElem = document.getElementById('myid');
        if (myElem === null){
            alert('does not exist!');
        }
        else{
            alert('it exist!');
        }
```

but if i use the same code in onAfterRendering method it is working fine.

Comment: Where are you calling the code if not in `onAfterRendering`?

Comment: At the time `onInit` is called, the View is not yet rendered, therefore you cannot access DOM elements yet. If you want to do manipulation with jQuery, you should do that in `onAfterRendering`.

Comment: hi i have some issues  with onAfterRendering.
my work flow will start from onInit, and from OnInit method i am doing ajax calls  to server side code to get drop down data.
onAfterRendering method called many times when ever view is renderd.

Comment: On each rendering your DOM is regenerated, so any modification you want to do has to be repeated after each rendering.